# Docker compose v3 - "Unsupported config option for volumes:"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have a yml file with a configuration to run two containers. Here's the file:

```
web:
  build: ./web
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - website:/www/

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    restart: always
    links:
     - web
    volumes:
     - website:/www/

volumes:
  website:
```

When I run this I always get the following error:

```
The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for volumes: 'website'
```

I have googled this and I think this is good as it is now. What is wrong with it?

Comment: please help to share your docker version as well as docker-compose version. Sometimes, we should have minimum combination for docker-compose to work.

Answer (score 2):

i think you should add `version` and `services` in docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
   build: ./web
   ports:
     - "8000:8000"
   restart: always
   volumes:
    - website:/www/

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    restart: always
    links:
     - web
    volumes:
     - website:/www/

volumes:
  website:
```

### reference :

- [docker compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)
- [getting start with docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/)